# Javascript - add a span for each letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to replace each letter of a div with many "span".

This code works except for letters with accents like "é". Can you help me please?

```
$('h2').each(function(){
  $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/(\w)/g, "<span>$&</span>"));
});
```

Comment: Just the letters? no numbers, spaces, !@#$^&..., etc?

Comment: Native JS regex has problems with Unicode characters. Do you need to wrap only letters, or any characters?

Comment: It works with space but it's a good idea to take numbers and special chars if it's possible. I don't know modify this regex... The more important are characters !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436824/matching-accented-characters-with-javascript-regexes

Comment: you can simplify the loop by using `$('h2').text(function(){
    return $(this).text().replace(/(\w)/g, "<span>$&</span>")
})`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try with following regex:

```
/([^\x00-\x80]|\w)/g
```

Comment: I know this is super old, but what if we need to also include characters like `& % / \ ( )`

Comment: It works. But in case you need to include i.g. a question mark?

Answer (score 5):

`\w` doesn't include diacritic symbols so you need to specify an unicode range, like this

```
/[a-z\u00C0-\u00F6\u00F8-\017E]/gi
```

Answer (score 3):

My variant without regexp

http://jsfiddle.net/d6pDG/

```
var html = $('.test').html();
var ret  = "";

$.each(html.split(''), function(k, v) {
   ret += "<span>" + v + "</span>";
});

$('.test').html(ret);
```