# Accented characters and regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, encoding, diacritics

I have this regexp:

```
(\b)(emozioni|gioia|felicità)(\b)
```

In a string like the one below:

```
emozioni emozioniamo felicità felicitàs
```

it should match the first and the third word. Instead it matches the first and the last. I assume it is because of the accented character. I tried this alternative:

```
(\b)(emozioni|gioia|felicità\s)(\b)
```

but it matched "felicità" only if there is an other word after it. So for being specific only if it is in this context:

```
emozioni emozioniamo felicità felicitàs
```

and not in this other:

```
emozioni emozioniamo felicitàs felicità
```

I've found an article about accented characters in French (so at the beginning of the word) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436824/matching-accented-characters-with-javascript-regexes), i followed the second answer. If anyone knows a better solution it is very welcome.

Comment: :) Please to meet you Valerio, do you have an "italian" solution?

Comment: Hanno già dato delle soluzioni, mi chiedevo perchè non splittare in array invece di usare le regex :) però non so che situazione è.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A word boundary `\b` works only with characters that are in `\w` character class, i.e `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`, thus you can't put a `\b` after an accentued character like `à`.

You can solve the problem in your case using a lookahead:

```
felicità(?=\s|$)
```

or shorter:

```
felicità(?!\S)
```

(or `\W` in place of `\s` as suggested @Sniffer, but you take the risk to match something like :`felicitàà`)

Comment: @softwareplay Check the demo link I posted, it is working all right.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following alternative:

```
\b(emozioni|gioia|felicità)(?=\W|$)
```

This will match any of your listed words, as long as any of those words is followed by either a non-word character `\W` or end-of-string `$`.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yB3fL0)

Comment: @softwareplay If you are **not forced** to use that `\b` then don't worry, what ever words you put in that list, this would work.

Comment: @Sniffer Considering the fact that JS does not support lookbehinds do you have a solution for words _starting_ with accented characters?