# How to validate a unicode email?

Tags: regex, validation, email, unicode

Since

> In October 2009, the Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers (ICANN) approved the creation of country code top-level domains (ccTLDs) in the Internet that use the IDNA standard for native language scripts.

We just validate the a-zA-Z at in the past. But now, I want to validate a unicode email such as a Chinese email `我@在.中国` or other languages. How to validate them by RegExp?

Comment: Email addresses can have a lot more characters than just `a-zA-Z` in them.  Why not just trust your users to enter a correct address?

Comment: The only reliable way to do this is send an email to recipient, and require a confirmation. There's relatively little or no value in knowing that an email address is "valid", value is in knowing (confirming) that it belongs to someone. To ensure a legitimate looking email, test for an "@" is usually enough.  

[here](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/), [here](http://jacobsantos.com/blog/2007/general/stop-doing-email-validation-the-wrong-way), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address])

Comment: Sorry, I still think it's necessary. First, Servers send email frequently is inefficient. And I'm afraid safety problem when special characters are sent to servers.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a validation regex that I wrote for maximum Unicode support and reasonably good overall adherence to RFC standards.

JS:

```
/^(?!\.)((?!.*\.{2})[a-zA-Z0-9\u0080-\u00FF\u0100-\u017F\u0180-\u024F\u0250-\u02AF\u0300-\u036F\u0370-\u03FF\u0400-\u04FF\u0500-\u052F\u0530-\u058F\u0590-\u05FF\u0600-\u06FF\u0700-\u074F\u0750-\u077F\u0780-\u07BF\u07C0-\u07FF\u0900-\u097F\u0980-\u09FF\u0A00-\u0A7F\u0A80-\u0AFF\u0B00-\u0B7F\u0B80-\u0BFF\u0C00-\u0C7F\u0C80-\u0CFF\u0D00-\u0D7F\u0D80-\u0DFF\u0E00-\u0E7F\u0E80-\u0EFF\u0F00-\u0FFF\u1000-\u109F\u10A0-\u10FF\u1100-\u11FF\u1200-\u137F\u1380-\u139F\u13A0-\u13FF\u1400-\u167F\u1680-\u169F\u16A0-\u16FF\u1700-\u171F\u1720-\u173F\u1740-\u175F\u1760-\u177F\u1780-\u17FF\u1800-\u18AF\u1900-\u194F\u1950-\u197F\u1980-\u19DF\u19E0-\u19FF\u1A00-\u1A1F\u1B00-\u1B7F\u1D00-\u1D7F\u1D80-\u1DBF\u1DC0-\u1DFF\u1E00-\u1EFF\u1F00-\u1FFF\u20D0-\u20FF\u2100-\u214F\u2C00-\u2C5F\u2C60-\u2C7F\u2C80-\u2CFF\u2D00-\u2D2F\u2D30-\u2D7F\u2D80-\u2DDF\u2F00-\u2FDF\u2FF0-\u2FFF\u3040-\u309F\u30A0-\u30FF\u3100-\u312F\u3130-\u318F\u3190-\u319F\u31C0-\u31EF\u31F0-\u31FF\u3200-\u32FF\u3300-\u33FF\u3400-\u4DBF\u4DC0-\u4DFF\u4E00-\u9FFF\uA000-\uA48F\uA490-\uA4CF\uA700-\uA71F\uA800-\uA82F\uA840-\uA87F\uAC00-\uD7AF\uF900-\uFAFF\.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~\-\d]+)@(?!\.)([a-zA-Z0-9\u0080-\u00FF\u0100-\u017F\u0180-\u024F\u0250-\u02AF\u0300-\u036F\u0370-\u03FF\u0400-\u04FF\u0500-\u052F\u0530-\u058F\u0590-\u05FF\u0600-\u06FF\u0700-\u074F\u0750-\u077F\u0780-\u07BF\u07C0-\u07FF\u0900-\u097F\u0980-\u09FF\u0A00-\u0A7F\u0A80-\u0AFF\u0B00-\u0B7F\u0B80-\u0BFF\u0C00-\u0C7F\u0C80-\u0CFF\u0D00-\u0D7F\u0D80-\u0DFF\u0E00-\u0E7F\u0E80-\u0EFF\u0F00-\u0FFF\u1000-\u109F\u10A0-\u10FF\u1100-\u11FF\u1200-\u137F\u1380-\u139F\u13A0-\u13FF\u1400-\u167F\u1680-\u169F\u16A0-\u16FF\u1700-\u171F\u1720-\u173F\u1740-\u175F\u1760-\u177F\u1780-\u17FF\u1800-\u18AF\u1900-\u194F\u1950-\u197F\u1980-\u19DF\u19E0-\u19FF\u1A00-\u1A1F\u1B00-\u1B7F\u1D00-\u1D7F\u1D80-\u1DBF\u1DC0-\u1DFF\u1E00-\u1EFF\u1F00-\u1FFF\u20D0-\u20FF\u2100-\u214F\u2C00-\u2C5F\u2C60-\u2C7F\u2C80-\u2CFF\u2D00-\u2D2F\u2D30-\u2D7F\u2D80-\u2DDF\u2F00-\u2FDF\u2FF0-\u2FFF\u3040-\u309F\u30A0-\u30FF\u3100-\u312F\u3130-\u318F\u3190-\u319F\u31C0-\u31EF\u31F0-\u31FF\u3200-\u32FF\u3300-\u33FF\u3400-\u4DBF\u4DC0-\u4DFF\u4E00-\u9FFF\uA000-\uA48F\uA490-\uA4CF\uA700-\uA71F\uA800-\uA82F\uA840-\uA87F\uAC00-\uD7AF\uF900-\uFAFF\-\.\d]+)((\.([a-zA-Z\u0080-\u00FF\u0100-\u017F\u0180-\u024F\u0250-\u02AF\u0300-\u036F\u0370-\u03FF\u0400-\u04FF\u0500-\u052F\u0530-\u058F\u0590-\u05FF\u0600-\u06FF\u0700-\u074F\u0750-\u077F\u0780-\u07BF\u07C0-\u07FF\u0900-\u097F\u0980-\u09FF\u0A00-\u0A7F\u0A80-\u0AFF\u0B00-\u0B7F\u0B80-\u0BFF\u0C00-\u0C7F\u0C80-\u0CFF\u0D00-\u0D7F\u0D80-\u0DFF\u0E00-\u0E7F\u0E80-\u0EFF\u0F00-\u0FFF\u1000-\u109F\u10A0-\u10FF\u1100-\u11FF\u1200-\u137F\u1380-\u139F\u13A0-\u13FF\u1400-\u167F\u1680-\u169F\u16A0-\u16FF\u1700-\u171F\u1720-\u173F\u1740-\u175F\u1760-\u177F\u1780-\u17FF\u1800-\u18AF\u1900-\u194F\u1950-\u197F\u1980-\u19DF\u19E0-\u19FF\u1A00-\u1A1F\u1B00-\u1B7F\u1D00-\u1D7F\u1D80-\u1DBF\u1DC0-\u1DFF\u1E00-\u1EFF\u1F00-\u1FFF\u20D0-\u20FF\u2100-\u214F\u2C00-\u2C5F\u2C60-\u2C7F\u2C80-\u2CFF\u2D00-\u2D2F\u2D30-\u2D7F\u2D80-\u2DDF\u2F00-\u2FDF\u2FF0-\u2FFF\u3040-\u309F\u30A0-\u30FF\u3100-\u312F\u3130-\u318F\u3190-\u319F\u31C0-\u31EF\u31F0-\u31FF\u3200-\u32FF\u3300-\u33FF\u3400-\u4DBF\u4DC0-\u4DFF\u4E00-\u9FFF\uA000-\uA48F\uA490-\uA4CF\uA700-\uA71F\uA800-\uA82F\uA840-\uA87F\uAC00-\uD7AF\uF900-\uFAFF]){2,63})+)$/i
```

PHP:

```
/^(?!\.)((?!.*\.{2})[a-zA-Z0-9\x{0080}-\x{00FF}\x{0100}-\x{017F}\x{0180}-\x{024F}\x{0250}-\x{02AF}\x{0300}-\x{036F}\x{0370}-\x{03FF}\x{0400}-\x{04FF}\x{0500}-\x{052F}\x{0530}-\x{058F}\x{0590}-\x{05FF}\x{0600}-\x{06FF}\x{0700}-\x{074F}\x{0750}-\x{077F}\x{0780}-\x{07BF}\x{07C0}-\x{07FF}\x{0900}-\x{097F}\x{0980}-\x{09FF}\x{0A00}-\x{0A7F}\x{0A80}-\x{0AFF}\x{0B00}-\x{0B7F}\x{0B80}-\x{0BFF}\x{0C00}-\x{0C7F}\x{0C80}-\x{0CFF}\x{0D00}-\x{0D7F}\x{0D80}-\x{0DFF}\x{0E00}-\x{0E7F}\x{0E80}-\x{0EFF}\x{0F00}-\x{0FFF}\x{1000}-\x{109F}\x{10A0}-\x{10FF}\x{1100}-\x{11FF}\x{1200}-\x{137F}\x{1380}-\x{139F}\x{13A0}-\x{13FF}\x{1400}-\x{167F}\x{1680}-\x{169F}\x{16A0}-\x{16FF}\x{1700}-\x{171F}\x{1720}-\x{173F}\x{1740}-\x{175F}\x{1760}-\x{177F}\x{1780}-\x{17FF}\x{1800}-\x{18AF}\x{1900}-\x{194F}\x{1950}-\x{197F}\x{1980}-\x{19DF}\x{19E0}-\x{19FF}\x{1A00}-\x{1A1F}\x{1B00}-\x{1B7F}\x{1D00}-\x{1D7F}\x{1D80}-\x{1DBF}\x{1DC0}-\x{1DFF}\x{1E00}-\x{1EFF}\x{1F00}-\x{1FFF}\x{20D0}-\x{20FF}\x{2100}-\x{214F}\x{2C00}-\x{2C5F}\x{2C60}-\x{2C7F}\x{2C80}-\x{2CFF}\x{2D00}-\x{2D2F}\x{2D30}-\x{2D7F}\x{2D80}-\x{2DDF}\x{2F00}-\x{2FDF}\x{2FF0}-\x{2FFF}\x{3040}-\x{309F}\x{30A0}-\x{30FF}\x{3100}-\x{312F}\x{3130}-\x{318F}\x{3190}-\x{319F}\x{31C0}-\x{31EF}\x{31F0}-\x{31FF}\x{3200}-\x{32FF}\x{3300}-\x{33FF}\x{3400}-\x{4DBF}\x{4DC0}-\x{4DFF}\x{4E00}-\x{9FFF}\x{A000}-\x{A48F}\x{A490}-\x{A4CF}\x{A700}-\x{A71F}\x{A800}-\x{A82F}\x{A840}-\x{A87F}\x{AC00}-\x{D7AF}\x{F900}-\x{FAFF}\.!#$%&'*+-\/=?^_`{|}~\-\d]+)@(?!\.)([a-zA-Z0-9\x{0080}-\x{00FF}\x{0100}-\x{017F}\x{0180}-\x{024F}\x{0250}-\x{02AF}\x{0300}-\x{036F}\x{0370}-\x{03FF}\x{0400}-\x{04FF}\x{0500}-\x{052F}\x{0530}-\x{058F}\x{0590}-\x{05FF}\x{0600}-\x{06FF}\x{0700}-\x{074F}\x{0750}-\x{077F}\x{0780}-\x{07BF}\x{07C0}-\x{07FF}\x{0900}-\x{097F}\x{0980}-\x{09FF}\x{0A00}-\x{0A7F}\x{0A80}-\x{0AFF}\x{0B00}-\x{0B7F}\x{0B80}-\x{0BFF}\x{0C00}-\x{0C7F}\x{0C80}-\x{0CFF}\x{0D00}-\x{0D7F}\x{0D80}-\x{0DFF}\x{0E00}-\x{0E7F}\x{0E80}-\x{0EFF}\x{0F00}-\x{0FFF}\x{1000}-\x{109F}\x{10A0}-\x{10FF}\x{1100}-\x{11FF}\x{1200}-\x{137F}\x{1380}-\x{139F}\x{13A0}-\x{13FF}\x{1400}-\x{167F}\x{1680}-\x{169F}\x{16A0}-\x{16FF}\x{1700}-\x{171F}\x{1720}-\x{173F}\x{1740}-\x{175F}\x{1760}-\x{177F}\x{1780}-\x{17FF}\x{1800}-\x{18AF}\x{1900}-\x{194F}\x{1950}-\x{197F}\x{1980}-\x{19DF}\x{19E0}-\x{19FF}\x{1A00}-\x{1A1F}\x{1B00}-\x{1B7F}\x{1D00}-\x{1D7F}\x{1D80}-\x{1DBF}\x{1DC0}-\x{1DFF}\x{1E00}-\x{1EFF}\x{1F00}-\x{1FFF}\x{20D0}-\x{20FF}\x{2100}-\x{214F}\x{2C00}-\x{2C5F}\x{2C60}-\x{2C7F}\x{2C80}-\x{2CFF}\x{2D00}-\x{2D2F}\x{2D30}-\x{2D7F}\x{2D80}-\x{2DDF}\x{2F00}-\x{2FDF}\x{2FF0}-\x{2FFF}\x{3040}-\x{309F}\x{30A0}-\x{30FF}\x{3100}-\x{312F}\x{3130}-\x{318F}\x{3190}-\x{319F}\x{31C0}-\x{31EF}\x{31F0}-\x{31FF}\x{3200}-\x{32FF}\x{3300}-\x{33FF}\x{3400}-\x{4DBF}\x{4DC0}-\x{4DFF}\x{4E00}-\x{9FFF}\x{A000}-\x{A48F}\x{A490}-\x{A4CF}\x{A700}-\x{A71F}\x{A800}-\x{A82F}\x{A840}-\x{A87F}\x{AC00}-\x{D7AF}\x{F900}-\x{FAFF}\-\.\d]+)((\.([a-zA-Z\x{0080}-\x{00FF}\x{0100}-\x{017F}\x{0180}-\x{024F}\x{0250}-\x{02AF}\x{0300}-\x{036F}\x{0370}-\x{03FF}\x{0400}-\x{04FF}\x{0500}-\x{052F}\x{0530}-\x{058F}\x{0590}-\x{05FF}\x{0600}-\x{06FF}\x{0700}-\x{074F}\x{0750}-\x{077F}\x{0780}-\x{07BF}\x{07C0}-\x{07FF}\x{0900}-\x{097F}\x{0980}-\x{09FF}\x{0A00}-\x{0A7F}\x{0A80}-\x{0AFF}\x{0B00}-\x{0B7F}\x{0B80}-\x{0BFF}\x{0C00}-\x{0C7F}\x{0C80}-\x{0CFF}\x{0D00}-\x{0D7F}\x{0D80}-\x{0DFF}\x{0E00}-\x{0E7F}\x{0E80}-\x{0EFF}\x{0F00}-\x{0FFF}\x{1000}-\x{109F}\x{10A0}-\x{10FF}\x{1100}-\x{11FF}\x{1200}-\x{137F}\x{1380}-\x{139F}\x{13A0}-\x{13FF}\x{1400}-\x{167F}\x{1680}-\x{169F}\x{16A0}-\x{16FF}\x{1700}-\x{171F}\x{1720}-\x{173F}\x{1740}-\x{175F}\x{1760}-\x{177F}\x{1780}-\x{17FF}\x{1800}-\x{18AF}\x{1900}-\x{194F}\x{1950}-\x{197F}\x{1980}-\x{19DF}\x{19E0}-\x{19FF}\x{1A00}-\x{1A1F}\x{1B00}-\x{1B7F}\x{1D00}-\x{1D7F}\x{1D80}-\x{1DBF}\x{1DC0}-\x{1DFF}\x{1E00}-\x{1EFF}\x{1F00}-\x{1FFF}\x{20D0}-\x{20FF}\x{2100}-\x{214F}\x{2C00}-\x{2C5F}\x{2C60}-\x{2C7F}\x{2C80}-\x{2CFF}\x{2D00}-\x{2D2F}\x{2D30}-\x{2D7F}\x{2D80}-\x{2DDF}\x{2F00}-\x{2FDF}\x{2FF0}-\x{2FFF}\x{3040}-\x{309F}\x{30A0}-\x{30FF}\x{3100}-\x{312F}\x{3130}-\x{318F}\x{3190}-\x{319F}\x{31C0}-\x{31EF}\x{31F0}-\x{31FF}\x{3200}-\x{32FF}\x{3300}-\x{33FF}\x{3400}-\x{4DBF}\x{4DC0}-\x{4DFF}\x{4E00}-\x{9FFF}\x{A000}-\x{A48F}\x{A490}-\x{A4CF}\x{A700}-\x{A71F}\x{A800}-\x{A82F}\x{A840}-\x{A87F}\x{AC00}-\x{D7AF}\x{F900}-\x{FAFF}]){2,63})+)$/u
```

Besides RFC rules, the Unicode part above consists of a series of ranges of character subsets. This is done so that only real letters and numbers enter the validation, while non-Latin punctuation and miscellaneous Unicode characters are rejected.

The main things that don't validate correctly at this time are IP addresses in place of domain names, comments inside the "local" part, apostrophes, and forward slashes. I've never seen anyone use the latter two so didn't bother bloating the regex to support them.

You can find a live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/aossikine/qCLVH/3/

Here is a breakdown of characters allowed by RFC standards and whether they are supported by this regex:

- `a-zA-Z0-9`
- `` !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~ ``
- `(),:;<>@[]` (must be between quotation marks)

  - this one is not yet implemented
- `.` (period cannot be the first or last character, shouldn't appear consecutively)
- `\`(must be preceded by a backslash)

  - this one is not yet implemented
- `"` (must be preceded by a backslash)

  - this one is not yet implemented
- strip out anything surrounded by parenthesis from the start or end of the local part

  - this one is not yet implemented
- domain name can only contain letters, numbers, and dashes (and dashes may be consecutive)

For details on RFC standards, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address#Syntax. Most of the logic detailed there is supported. The JSFiddle link above includes some additional documentation and additional links to handy sites.

Comment: Your regexp is missing special characters like é, î or ñ. I found this regexp on another anwser: \u00E0-\u00FC
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Internationalization and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436824/matching-accented-characters-with-javascript-regexes

Comment: Awesome! My visitors get to use ALL the bandwith on downloading just one regex! :D

Comment: @Kebman I would love to know if you have a better solution for validating email regexes with Unicode support. If you do, please comment here.

Answer (score 3):

Validating an IDNA domain name properly is impossible with regexes. It basically involves the [ToASCII](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3490#section-4.1) operation defined in RFC3490. For every domain label the following steps must be executed:

- [NAMEPREP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3491) processing as defined in RFC3491 which requires:

  - Mapping of code points using tables from RFC 3454 (STRINGPREP).
  - Conversion to Unicode Normalization Form NFKC.
  - Check for prohibited code points using tables from RFC 3454.
  - Check bidirectional characters as defined in RFC 3454.
- Check ASCII characters.
- Encode using Punycode.
- Check that the result doesn't exceed 63 characters.

You should use an IDNA library for your language of choice.

**EDIT:** The answer above refers to the old IDNA standard which has been superseded by RFC 5890 ff. The latter is inclusion-based but it's still too complicated to verify a domain name with a regex.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
\u0900-\u097F\u0980-\u09FF\u0A00-\u0A7F\u0A80-\u0AFF\u0B00-\u0B7F\u0B80-\u0BFF\u0C00-\u0C7F\u0C80-\u0CFF\u0D00-\u0D7F\u0D80-\u0DFF\u0E00-\u0E7F\u0E80-\u0EFF\u0F00-\u0FFF\u1000-\u109F\u1700-\u171F\u1720-\u173F\u1740-\u175F\u1760-\u177F\u1780-\u17FF\u1900-\u194F\u1950-\u197F\u1980-\u19DF\u19E0-\u19FF\u1A00-\u1A1F\u1A20-\u1AAF\u1B00-\u1B7F\u1B80-\u1BBF\u1BC0-\u1BFF\u1C00-\u1C4F\u1CC0-\u1CCF\uA800-\uA82F\uA840-\uA87F\uA880-\uA8DF\uA8E0-\uA8FF\uA930-\uA95F\uA980-\uA9DF\uA9E0-\uA9FF\uAA00-\uAA5F\uAA60-\uAA7F\uAA80-\uAADF\uAAE0-\uAAFF\uABC0-\uABFF\u0600-\u06FF\u0750–\u077F\u08A0–\u08FF\uFB50–\uFDFF\uFE70–\uFEFF\u4e00-\u9faf\u0D80-\u0DFF\u0E80-\u0EFF]/)!=null}e.exports=a}),null);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What type of language is that? What od all these unicode chars do?