# Regex For International Email Addresses (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Right now, I am trying to get international email addresses to validate... right now this regex works like a charm for email addresses:

```
/^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/
```

However, an international email address like this:
amartiñez@yahoo.com will not pass validation. How can I change the above regex to make this pass?

Comment: Please [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24817336/3832970). Does it solve the issue?

Comment: I think `ñ` character is messing with regx

Comment: I'm trying to get that to pass... how should I change the regex to make it pass?

Comment: It is `\u00F1`. [You can add it to your regex like this](https://regex101.com/r/fE1pE0/1). But I think the answer the link to which I provided must be a better solution.

Comment: Maube it can help you [Unicode range RegExp generator](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/js/regex#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include Spanish charset to your Regex

```
^[_a-zA-ZáéíñóúüÁÉÍÑÓÚÜ0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-ZáéíñóúüÁÉÍÑÓÚÜ0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jV4aN7/1)

Source: [Interesting Character Classes](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-interesting-character-classes.html)

Comment: This is only at most a patch work solution. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_email for examples of what international email can be.