# regex to validate non-english characters

Tags: javascript

I have seen other similar answers and have incorporated some of them but still not quite getting it.
Please, the javascript regex below can validate the following emails:

1.**θσερ@gmail.com**
but not :
2.**θσερ@εχαμπλε.ψομ**

js regex:

```
^([\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF\w-\.+]+)@(([\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]{1,3}\.)|(\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,10}|[0-9]{1,3}|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])(\]?)$
```

anyone willing to point me to why it fails for the second email?

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - do you want it to find non-ascii characters or not find them? As in, should it match both those emails or should it not match either? The simplest way would be to have a simple regex that only matches regular ascii/english letters ^[a-zA-Z0-9?><;,{}[\]\-_+=!@#$%\^&*|']*$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: @CarlosAlexandre, might be a duplicate but that link don't have solution for what I am trying to do.

Comment: @JonLuca, Sorry. I want it to also match the second email as well. I am interested in it matching non-ascii/english characters as well.

Comment: Have You already tried? Your regex contain a bunch of specific chars that it's complicated to ensure proper validation. Try a more global regex validating email format and report here please.

Comment: @CarlosAlexandre sorry, is there a more global regex validating email format? if you mean like just checking for @\ that isn't what I am looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate a unicode email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461943/how-to-validate-a-unicode-email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
/^(?!\.)((?!.*\.{2})[a-zA-Z0-9\u0080-\u00FF\u0100-\u017F\u0180-\u024F\u0250-\u02AF\u0300-\u036F\u0370-\u03FF\u0400-\u04FF\u0500-\u052F\u0530-\u058F\u0590-\u05FF\u0600-\u06FF\u0700-\u074F\u0750-\u077F\u0780-\u07BF\u07C0-\u07FF\u0900-\u097F\u0980-\u09FF\u0A00-\u0A7F\u0A80-\u0AFF\u0B00-\u0B7F\u0B80-\u0BFF\u0C00-\u0C7F\u0C80-\u0CFF\u0D00-\u0D7F\u0D80-\u0DFF\u0E00-\u0E7F\u0E80-\u0EFF\u0F00-\u0FFF\u1000-\u109F\u10A0-\u10FF\u1100-\u11FF\u1200-\u137F\u1380-\u139F\u13A0-\u13FF\u1400-\u167F\u1680-\u169F\u16A0-\u16FF\u1700-\u171F\u1720-\u173F\u1740-\u175F\u1760-\u177F\u1780-\u17FF\u1800-\u18AF\u1900-\u194F\u1950-\u197F\u1980-\u19DF\u19E0-\u19FF\u1A00-\u1A1F\u1B00-\u1B7F\u1D00-\u1D7F\u1D80-\u1DBF\u1DC0-\u1DFF\u1E00-\u1EFF\u1F00-\u1FFF\u20D0-\u20FF\u2100-\u214F\u2C00-\u2C5F\u2C60-\u2C7F\u2C80-\u2CFF\u2D00-\u2D2F\u2D30-\u2D7F\u2D80-\u2DDF\u2F00-\u2FDF\u2FF0-\u2FFF\u3040-\u309F\u30A0-\u30FF\u3100-\u312F\u3130-\u318F\u3190-\u319F\u31C0-\u31EF\u31F0-\u31FF\u3200-\u32FF\u3300-\u33FF\u3400-\u4DBF\u4DC0-\u4DFF\u4E00-\u9FFF\uA000-\uA48F\uA490-\uA4CF\uA700-\uA71F\uA800-\uA82F\uA840-\uA87F\uAC00-\uD7AF\uF900-\uFAFF\.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~\-\d]+)@(?!\.)([a-zA-Z0-9\u0080-\u00FF\u0100-\u017F\u0180-\u024F\u0250-\u02AF\u0300-\u036F\u0370-\u03FF\u0400-\u04FF\u0500-\u052F\u0530-\u058F\u0590-\u05FF\u0600-\u06FF\u0700-\u074F\u0750-\u077F\u0780-\u07BF\u07C0-\u07FF\u0900-\u097F\u0980-\u09FF\u0A00-\u0A7F\u0A80-\u0AFF\u0B00-\u0B7F\u0B80-\u0BFF\u0C00-\u0C7F\u0C80-\u0CFF\u0D00-\u0D7F\u0D80-\u0DFF\u0E00-\u0E7F\u0E80-\u0EFF\u0F00-\u0FFF\u1000-\u109F\u10A0-\u10FF\u1100-\u11FF\u1200-\u137F\u1380-\u139F\u13A0-\u13FF\u1400-\u167F\u1680-\u169F\u16A0-\u16FF\u1700-\u171F\u1720-\u173F\u1740-\u175F\u1760-\u177F\u1780-\u17FF\u1800-\u18AF\u1900-\u194F\u1950-\u197F\u1980-\u19DF\u19E0-\u19FF\u1A00-\u1A1F\u1B00-\u1B7F\u1D00-\u1D7F\u1D80-\u1DBF\u1DC0-\u1DFF\u1E00-\u1EFF\u1F00-\u1FFF\u20D0-\u20FF\u2100-\u214F\u2C00-\u2C5F\u2C60-\u2C7F\u2C80-\u2CFF\u2D00-\u2D2F\u2D30-\u2D7F\u2D80-\u2DDF\u2F00-\u2FDF\u2FF0-\u2FFF\u3040-\u309F\u30A0-\u30FF\u3100-\u312F\u3130-\u318F\u3190-\u319F\u31C0-\u31EF\u31F0-\u31FF\u3200-\u32FF\u3300-\u33FF\u3400-\u4DBF\u4DC0-\u4DFF\u4E00-\u9FFF\uA000-\uA48F\uA490-\uA4CF\uA700-\uA71F\uA800-\uA82F\uA840-\uA87F\uAC00-\uD7AF\uF900-\uFAFF\-\.\d]+)((\.([a-zA-Z\u0080-\u00FF\u0100-\u017F\u0180-\u024F\u0250-\u02AF\u0300-\u036F\u0370-\u03FF\u0400-\u04FF\u0500-\u052F\u0530-\u058F\u0590-\u05FF\u0600-\u06FF\u0700-\u074F\u0750-\u077F\u0780-\u07BF\u07C0-\u07FF\u0900-\u097F\u0980-\u09FF\u0A00-\u0A7F\u0A80-\u0AFF\u0B00-\u0B7F\u0B80-\u0BFF\u0C00-\u0C7F\u0C80-\u0CFF\u0D00-\u0D7F\u0D80-\u0DFF\u0E00-\u0E7F\u0E80-\u0EFF\u0F00-\u0FFF\u1000-\u109F\u10A0-\u10FF\u1100-\u11FF\u1200-\u137F\u1380-\u139F\u13A0-\u13FF\u1400-\u167F\u1680-\u169F\u16A0-\u16FF\u1700-\u171F\u1720-\u173F\u1740-\u175F\u1760-\u177F\u1780-\u17FF\u1800-\u18AF\u1900-\u194F\u1950-\u197F\u1980-\u19DF\u19E0-\u19FF\u1A00-\u1A1F\u1B00-\u1B7F\u1D00-\u1D7F\u1D80-\u1DBF\u1DC0-\u1DFF\u1E00-\u1EFF\u1F00-\u1FFF\u20D0-\u20FF\u2100-\u214F\u2C00-\u2C5F\u2C60-\u2C7F\u2C80-\u2CFF\u2D00-\u2D2F\u2D30-\u2D7F\u2D80-\u2DDF\u2F00-\u2FDF\u2FF0-\u2FFF\u3040-\u309F\u30A0-\u30FF\u3100-\u312F\u3130-\u318F\u3190-\u319F\u31C0-\u31EF\u31F0-\u31FF\u3200-\u32FF\u3300-\u33FF\u3400-\u4DBF\u4DC0-\u4DFF\u4E00-\u9FFF\uA000-\uA48F\uA490-\uA4CF\uA700-\uA71F\uA800-\uA82F\uA840-\uA87F\uAC00-\uD7AF\uF900-\uFAFF]){2,63})+)$/i
```

for JavaScript validation for unicode characters.

Original source: [How to validate a unicode email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461943/how-to-validate-a-unicode-email)

Comment: Thanks mate! You must be the regex expert :D every single unicode was copied in there I guess.

Comment: It's bad form to copy and paste a solution from elsewhere without linking to its source.