# android spinner with accents string

Tags: android

I have a spinner with accents string

```
<string-array name="typelist">
        <item>Médicament</item>
        <item>Pharmacie</item>
    </string-array>
```

When I insert them in the database, they are added with weird characters

```
final String drop = typelist.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

How can I correct this error please

Comment: what is it adding??

Comment: In my database I found MÃ©dicament instead of Médicament

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436824/matching-accented-characters-with-javascript-regexes

Comment: you need to create regex and match with letters

Comment: Please post how you insert your data into the database.

Comment: params.put("type", drop);
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String s = rh.sendPostRequest(Register_URL, params);   PHP code $nom=$_POST['nom'];
$type=$_POST['type']; $q3= mysql_query("INSERT INTO prod (Nom,Type) VALUES ('$nom','$type')");

Answer (score -1):

Please check following code

it works for me

My be it help you

**this is my string**

```
String string = "éàù";
```

**Solution**

```
  string = Normalizer.normalize(string, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        string = string.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");

        Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I don't think removing the accents is what she/he wants but displaying them properly.

Comment: @user13 yes I want to display them properly

Comment: @user13 Im just write what i have done may it helpfull to others